# dynamically assign name to key python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if the title describes the problem correctly, so take a look:

```
def get_outer_edges(df, col):
    # first drop all zeros
    df[df.number != 0] #REPLACE NUMBER WITH col FROM ARGUMENTS ABOVE.
    ....
```

df.`number` is the name of the column that I'd like to filter on.

What I'd like to do is be able to say

df.`col` instead of df.`number` but `col` is a variable containing the string 'number'

how do I do this?

```
def get_outer_edges(df, col):
    # first drop all zeros
    df[df.col != 0]
```

Also, what is this type of programming called? not 'dynamic programming' it has a name though right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
df[getattr(df, col) != 0]
```